# How to initialize project when it is imported

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an eclipse plugin and a custom project type. When the project is created through the wizard i can do as much setup code as i want. While using the plugin an .xml file is created containing plugin specific information about some resources inside the project.

Now when the project is checked into a versioning system the xml file is included. When someone checks out the project into eclipse again i would have to read the .xml file and apply the information to the resources again.

Is there a place where i can put code that is executed when a project of my custom project nature is beeing imported from somewhere else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `IResourceChangeListener` to listen for resource changes.

Your listener should get an `IResourceDelta` for the project with the 'kind' flag set to `IResourceDelta.ADDED`.

Comment: This seems to be a good way, thanks so far! I tried it in a few different ways (with and without visitor) but i can't get the point in time where the entire project has been added. I always get notified for every single resource that is added in the hierarchy. Dou you have a hint for this?#

Comment: Resource change events are usually batched up and sent at the end of an operation, but I don't know of a way to be certain that the operation has finished.